# What is the correct argument to pthread_create

Tags: c, pthreads, function-pointers

I have seen the documentation of [pthread_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html)

In the example at the bottom they are using:

```
pthread_create(&tinfo[tnum].thread_id, &attr, &thread_start, &tinfo[tnum]);
```

`&thread_start` - with `&`

but in other examples I have seen online they were not using the `&`:

```
pthread_create(&tinfo[tnum].thread_id, &attr, thread_start, &tinfo[tnum]);
```

I have also tested and it works without `&`.

But which is the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: both are correct.

---

The signature of `pthread_create` is:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

So `start_routine` is a function pointer that takes a `void *` argument and returns `void *`.

Back to your question, I assume `thread_start` is the name of the function, so `&thread_start` is a function pointer which is correct.

However, `thread_start` is correct, too, because the function name is automatically converted to a function pointer.